# magento2 decrypt problem not getting real value

Tags: magento2

I encrypt code id using below code

```
$this->_encryptor->encrypt($quote->getId())
```

when I decrypt with below code

```
$this->_encryptor->decrypt($quoteId);
```

It is not getting real value for some problem of special character.

Answer (score 1):

please try this code and check it's working or not

```
$this->_encryptor->encrypt((int)$quote->getId())
```

also try this code

```
        $this->_dataSaveAllowed = false;
        $value = (int)$quote->getId();
        // don't save value, if an obscured value was received. This indicates that data was not changed.
        if (!preg_match('/^\*+$/', $value) && !empty($value)) {
            $this->_dataSaveAllowed = true;
            $encrypted = $this->_encryptor->encrypt($value);
            $this->setValue($encrypted);
        } elseif (empty($value)) {
            $this->_dataSaveAllowed = true;
        }

        $this->_encryptor->decrypt($value);
```

Comment: no ites not work for me.

Comment: some times its work like for value 5 its work but for vlaue 6 its not work